# A file reading function

Tags: c++, string, file-io, vector

I need to write a function to read from a file, and ideally to store the strings from that file into a `vector` of `string`s.

So far I have something like this:

```
void loadCars() {
    fstream carFile;
    string car;
    carFile.open("car.txt");
    if (carFile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(carFile, car)) {
            cout << car << "\n";
        }
        carFile.close();
    } else {
        cout << "unable to open file" << endl;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me, all I need the function to do is read from a text file which contains four strings:

> car1
>   car2
>   car3
>   car4

And I want to read them and put them into a vector ideally. The `cout` is purely for me trying to test that it works, but it was unable to open the file.

Comment: what is a specific problem that you are facing?

Comment: Does the program read back to you `"unable to open file"`? If so, is the file in the directory of your executable?

Comment: If you can't open the file, odds are your current working directory isn't where you think it is. A quick exec of [`getcwd()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) and dumping the resulting directory to `std::cerr` will assist you in knowing "where" you are. There is also the possibility the file permissions don't allow you to open it, but that is a bit of a stretch. Finally, if this is running from Visual Studio, the folder where the *project* file (.vcprojx) is located is the default working directory for a debugger startup. Make sure your file is in the folder.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the feedback guys, I made an error in where I put the file. Since I previously wrote to file, it stored that file outside the debug folder. So i put the file out of that folder for reading, however i just put the cars file in the debug folder and it worked fine! thanks guys!

Comment: @JamesMillner Consider accepting one of the answers, if these helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and ideally to store the strings from that file into a vector of strings.

Just extend your function as follows, to collect results in a vector:

```
void loadCars(std::vector<std::string>& result) {
    result.clear();
    fstream carFile;
    string car;
    carFile.open("car.txt");
    if (carFile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(carFile, car)) {
            result.push_back(car);
            cout << car << "\n";
        }
        carFile.close();
    }
else {
        cout << "unable to open file" << endl;
    }
}
```

As for your problems opening the file, this might most likely happen because the file isn't available in your programs current working directory (check your debug settings), or you don't have access right on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a vector of strings, e.g.

```
#include <array>

std::vector<std::string> cars;

// Get your car...
cars.push_back(car);
```

See for example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector) for an up-to-date reference.